# Verify method call that accepts array of objects

Tags: java, junit, mockito, spring-test

I want to verify that the following method is called

```
MessageSourceAccessor.getMessage(String code, Object[] args, Locale locale)
```

with 10th member of `args` array equal to "CHF" and I don't want to check other members of this array.

So far I tried the following construction:

```
Object [] obj = new Object[] {anyObject(),
        anyObject(), anyObject(), anyObject(), anyObject(), anyObject(), anyObject(), anyObject(), anyObject(), "CHF", anyObject(), anyObject()};

verify(msa, times(1))
        .getMessage(eq("invoice.emailBody.1"), aryEq(obj), any(Locale.class));
```

Unfortunately mockito complains that I cannot use anyObject() in this case. On the other hand if I don't use it I must provide values for all of the array members which is not what I want.
Perhaps someone faced this issue before? If so, I would appreciate any help

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use an [ArgumentCaptor](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.8.47/org/mockito/ArgumentCaptor.html) to capture the `args` argument and then inspect the captured value to assert that the 10th member of `args` array is equal to "CHF". For example:

```
    msa.getMessage(code, args, aLocale);

    ArgumentCaptor<Object> captor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Object.class);
    Mockito.verify(mock).getMessage(Mockito.anyString(), (Object[]) captor.capture(), Mockito.any(Locale.class));

    List<Object> actualArgs = Arrays.asList((Object[]) captor.getValue());
    Assert.assertEquals(10, actualArgs.size());
    Assert.assertEquals("CHF", actualArgs.get(9));
}
```

Comment: You can now define an `ArgumentCaptor<Object>` which would save you from casting after `capture()` and `getValue()`